# What about Drupal Commons 3 on Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

What about Drupal Commons 3 on Drupal7?

Its still in alphas and betas for months. Is it worthwhile waiting till it mature? Or is progress already stalled?

At the time Commons 3 on D7 (1.0) comes out Commons 6 will be at least 2.15 (its already 2.11). Should I go with already matured Commons 2.11 or wait for the delaying Version?

Answer (score 0):

As of today [Drupal Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons) on Drupal.org, Commons Distribution Projects has reached version 7.x-3.22 from the first full release on February 25, 2013